# Angular 7 app is not loading in IE for the first time even if the polyfills are added

Tags: angular

Angular 7 app is not loading in IE for the first time even if the polyfills are added. After refreshing it is loading. After inspecting I have found that polyfills are not loading for the first time. I'm unable to find why polyfills are not loading for the first time.

**polyfills.ts**

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/* Fetch Polyfill for Angular */
import 'whatwg-fetch';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js'; // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
import 'web-animations-js'; // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags.ts';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.

/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
(window as any).global = window;
```

**package.json dependencies**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "@mdi/font": "^4.3.95",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.37.7",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "3.2.3",
    "intl-tel-input": "14.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "5.1.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "2.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.17.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
```

Comment: polyfills.ts should not be a json. Can you update?

Comment: @robert I'm really sorry about the mistake. I updated it.